# Query Tuning in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, sql-tuning

I need to tune this below query mentioned to avoid Union with the archive table every time because the below query might be unnecessarily scanning the Archive table even if in most of the cases the data will be present in the first table itself.

```
Procedure status(p_order_id in varchar2(25), p_stat out sys_refcursor) IS

Begin
open p_stat

select o.status_code,o.order_id FROM order o
where o.order_id=p_order_id 
union
select a.status_code,a.order_id FROM order_archive a
where a.order_id=p_order_id ;

end status;
```

Comment: Is there no `FROM` clause in your query, or am I getting tired?

Comment: If `order_id` is indexed (and highly selective) in both tables I'm not sure it would make that much difference, would it? Or does 'scanning' suggest the archive table isn't indexed? Do you actually have a performance issue or do you just think this looks wrong as it is?

Comment: Alex, order ID is the index.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `not exists` check against the main table as part of the archive branch:

```
select o.status_code,o.order_id
from order o
where o.order_id=p_order_id 
union all
select a.status_code,a.order_id
from order_archive a
where a.order_id=p_order_id
and not exists (
  select *
  from order o
  where o.order_id=p_order_id 
);
```

which now, of course, means it will look at the main table in both branches; but it may still be quicker, depending on your data, indexes, stats etc.

---

Another option, which will prevent the archive table being looked at if the ID exists in the main table, is to do a simple count against the main table first, and then conditionally open the ref cursor for one of two possible queries against a single table each; i.e. branching in PL/SQL instead of in SQL, eliminating the union completely. Something like:

```
procedure status(p_order_id in varchar2, p_stat out sys_refcursor) is
  l_count pls_integer;
begin
  select count(*) into l_count
  from order o
  where o.order_id=p_order_id;

  if l_count > 0 then
    -- exists in main table so only query that
    open p_stat for
      select o.status_code,o.order_id
      from order o
      where o.order_id=p_order_id;
  else
    -- does not exist in main table so only query archive
    open p_stat for
      select a.status_code,a.order_id
      from order_archive a
      where a.order_id=p_order_id;
  end if;
end status;
/
```

If the ID isn't unique in the main table then you could add `and rownum = 1` to the initial query so it stops as soon as it finds any matching rows (and therefore `l_count` can be at most 1) instead of getting an accurate count, since you don't really care about the actual number found.

> Can we use fetch and loop on the dataset of order table. If found then only go for archive table

Not really, because the fetch would consume the first row of the results. Here's a very contrived example:

```
var rc refcursor;

declare
  x varchar2(1);
begin
  open :rc for
    select 'A' from dual where 1 = 0
    union all
    select 'B' from dual where 1 = 0;
  fetch :rc into x;
  if :rc%notfound then
    open :rc for select 'C' from dual;
  end if;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

print rc

'
-
C
```

With this setup the 'main' query doesn't find any rows (because of the `1 = 0` check); after the fetch the cursor is `notfound`, so it reopens the cursor for the 'archive' query, and the caller sees that as expected.

But if the first query does return rows:

```
declare
  x varchar2(1);
begin
  open :rc for
    select 'A' from dual where 1=1
    union all
    select 'B' from dual where 1=1;
  fetch :rc into x;
  if :rc%notfound then
    open :rc for select 'C' from dual;
  end if;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

print rc

'
-
B
```

then after the fetch the cursor is `found` so it doesn't reopen the cursor for the archive query and the existing ref cursor is passed back to the caller. But the first row from the cursor has already been fetched into the `x` variable and is lost, so the caller no longer sees that. The `print` only shows a single row with `'B'`, and the other row that should be there with `'A'` is missing.

For the caller to still see both rows you would have to reopen the cursor with the 'main' query:

```
declare
  x varchar2(1);
begin
  open :rc for
    select 'A' from dual where 1=1
    union all
    select 'B' from dual where 1=1;
  fetch :rc into x;
  if :rc%found then
    open :rc for
      select 'A' from dual where 1=1
      union all
      select 'B' from dual where 1=1;
  else
    open :rc for select 'C' from dual;
  end if;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

print rc

'
-
A
B
```

Logically that would really be the same as the initial count I'm doing above, I suppose, but would be less clear.

Comment: Alex, can we use some temp variable in this and avoid any union at all. If we do not have any value in that temp value then only go for scanning Arc table. Because right now the execution time was improved but not to the extent I want it to improve.

Comment: @SudiptoSarkar - only by moving the exists check into a separate query, I think. I'm not sure that will make a lot of difference either. I've added an example though.

Comment: In my case 90% of time I will be getting my result from order table rather than going to archive at all.Can we use fetch and loop on the dataset of order table. If found then only go for archive table

Comment: Thanks Alex, Let me see it it improves the execution plan but this looks promising.

Comment: You can't open your cursor and examine what it found to decide whether to pass that back or re-open it against the archive; because you'd consume the first result from the cursor in doing so, via the fetch. You'd have to reopen the cursor - and requery the main table - for the caller to get all of the data back. The end result would be much the same as the standalone check I added, but would be more code and more complicated, without saving any time.

Comment: Alex, can we use some temp table to reuse the data fetched from               select o.status_code,o.order_id
      from order o
      where o.order_id=p_order_id;              call and use the dataset rather than fetching count?

Comment: Yes, but it's a bit more work. The overhead might be more than the cost of the count query. (That should be fast if it is indexed, so not sure why you need another approach.) That's really a different question now, so if you want to try that and get stuck you'll need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is simple to use `UNION ALL`, because the `UNION` guarantuert a `distinct` result of both tables.

Using `UNION ALL` will fetch the data from the first table and only after fetching all row from it it will access the second table.

`UNION` would be only required, if tehre are identical rows with  `order_id` and `status_code` in both tables and you need to dedup them; which is not a typical scenario.